# IE9, Opera, and older Safari try to download my Node.js server-hosted site as a file?

Tags: html, css, node.js

I... I am completely stumped. This makes absolutely no sense to me.

Now, I'm new to HTML5, CSS, and Javascript, but I feel like I've made a decent (unfinished) website design and a nice, simple (unfinished) server program using Node.js. The thing is though... is that it doesn't render in IE9, Opera, or Safari 5.0.6 or likely many other older versions of the browsers; rather it just tries to download the website as a file that has no extension. Yet it works in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari 5.1.7. (I haven't tested other browsers.)

I don't even know where to start as far as troubleshooting, and I'm hoping someone here can help me.
Hopefully it has something to do with my server configuration or code and an error on my part.

Sources - 
Server: http://pastebin.com/vzGnWfgr
HTML: http://pastebin.com/CvPBhmPa
CSS (If necessary): http://pastebin.com/WSAKxqxD

I also have the site live on my server here for now: http://test.kdude63.com/

Also, if it makes any difference, I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content type (MIME type) in your HTTP response is undefined, which I can see when I run a wireshark trace and see your server's 200 response.  If I go to http://test.kdude63.com/index.html, opera works fine as it didn't before and the content type is specified in the response.  This indicates to me that the handling to your main index page has an issue.

Chrome and firefox seem to handle this undefined data as text/html by default, which is why they have no issues displaying the page.

Also, I see that your case statement has a boolean expression which is not permitted and will lead any pages with an .htm extension to have the same problem as this.  Change this:

```
case '.html' || '.htm':
            contentType = 'text/html';
            break;
```

to this:

```
case '.html':
case '.htm':
            contentType = 'text/html';
            break;
```

Comment: Didn't work. I'm thinking the problem lies somewhere between lines 39 and 50 of server.js, but I have no idea what could be causing it. I noticed that at first it was returning `www//index.html` as the filepath, but I seem to have fixed that and still no cigar.

Comment: Oh. Looking here (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp), it shows that I can specify a default if nothing else matches. (Which I did, and it works.) What it was doing in the first place, was that it was getting the extension from the URL, not the filePath (which is unsurprising). With there being no file specified in the URL, it returns nothing. I don't know how I missed this, but thanks!

Comment: Great that the default statement fixed your issue.  I am still confused as to why it wouldn't work without it though.  Can you add a debug statement and see what content type you are getting for the root page?

Comment: Oh, I see that it _was_ supposed to be getting it from the filepath. I'm not exactly worried about it much more, but it's odd that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your site(http://test.kdude63.com/), response header of the page have `Content-Type: undefined`.

Many browsers just download the page when Content-Type is unknown MIME type. Check your app.js  or framework for the header setting.